# getURL in AS3, how to?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

Hello I have not used flash in years, and need to use some old tracking code in my new AS3 banner. I noticed that in 3.0 you can't place actionscript on objects themselves, just on the timeline.

I need to convert this As2 script which i would normally have on a button labeled 'my_button'

```
on (release) { 
getURL (_level0.clickTag, "_blank"); 
}
```

What is the equivalent code snippet to use on the timeline for my button labeled 'my_button'?

Comment: This isn't really the place to ask. Stuff like this is done in a completely different manner in AS3, and although this is easy to convert, it's much better to learn how it's done yourself so that you can apply it in any case, especially ones more complex than this. I would recommend looking up some tutorials on "event listeners", as that would be the main aspect you'd have to learn. Obviously the official AS3 Language Reference is also invaluable, I highly recommend looking there for any needed functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Google's clickTag suggestion:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import flash.net.URLRequest;

// ......

someButton_or_displayObject_to_receive_mouseClick.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
                   function(event: MouseEvent) : void {
                   flash.net.navigateToURL(new URLRequest(root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG), "_blank");
                   } 
);
```

Comment: your answer took me here http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1085684

Answer (score 3):

I saw a few diffrent examples, but none of them were identical to the method I use;

This is a full version, just copy and past and add in your URL AS3

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

// add event listener to listen for "btnOpen" click
btnOpen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,openFuction);

// add our openFuction
function openFuction(e:MouseEvent){
    var openPage:URLRequest=new URLRequest("https://mysite.co.uk")
    navigateToURL(openPage,"_blank");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's another way, as well, which doesn't necessarily rely on the use of the ExternalInterface class.  You could also try something like this (assuming your object on the stage has an instance name of "mybtn_mc":

```
mybtn_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openWebpage);
//
function openWebpage(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var my_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580069/geturl-in-as3-how-to/15639569");
    flash.net.navigateToURL(my_url, "_self");
}
// if you want the object to act like buttons do in AS2
// with the handcursor effect when you mouse over them,
// you would include the following lines:
mybtn_mc.buttonMode = true;
mybtn_mc.useHandCursor = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is written in timeline style, which is not something I approve of. But I sense you're not even close to ready to earning about Classes and how they work.

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openWebpage);

function openWebpage(e:MouseEvent):void {
   if (ExternalInterface.available) {
      var callReturn:String = ExternalInterface.call('function(){window.open("http://www.yourURL.com", "_blank", "top=0,left=0,width=800,height=600");}');
   }
}
```

Note that you should not be trying to reach outside the scope of the current MC, but how to do something else is beyond the scope of this answer har har. If interested, do a search on Dependency Injection.

Comment: Should note that he'll need the import for ExternalInterface. Also, navigateToUrl is another option for the opening a new window. (which would need it's own import as well.)

Comment: I sort of assume people know how to use intellisense, which adds the imports automatically.

Comment: Haha, I hear you. However I guess I get the feeling this is a Flash IDE situation. Also, if they cut/paste, then the intellisense is moot.  Was just making the suggestion since it seems as if they are moving from AS2 to AS3.

Comment: The IDE has intellisense. if you cut/paste, you can click at the end of the Class name you need to import and press Ctrl-Space.

Comment: I know that. you know that. Does the person here asking the question know that ? that's my point. As you said "But I sense you're not even close to ready to earning about Classes and how they work."  Was just trying to be helpful, no need to change anything ;)